# Reserved QUEUE name usage in WRITEQ TS

Tags: zos, cics

The IBM documentation for WRITEQ TS states:

"Do not use X'FA' through X'FF', or **, or $$, or DF, as the first character of the name; these characters are reserved for CICS use."

What are each of those prefixes used for?

Presumably one of them would be used for EXEC CICS START REQID; which one of them is for that?

How is X'FA'-X'FF' mapped into Ascii when run under TX-Series on AIX?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for this but, I found this reference to [CEMT INQUIRE TSQUEUE / TSQNAME](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.systemprogramming.doc/transactions/cemt/dfha7mo.html) that explains a little about some of the reserved characters.

The INQUIRE TSQUEUE command returns information about temporary storage (TS) queues. The INQUIRE TSQUEUE command operates on all the temporary storage queues that exist in the CICS® region. Temporary storage queues that CICS creates internally for its own use, for example, queues used by BMS, are included. You can identify the temporary storage queues that CICS creates for its own use by queue names that begin with the following character strings:
**              BMS paging
$$              BMS route
X'FA' to X'FF'  CICS
CEBR            Default CEBR queue name
DF              CICS
DFHM            Message cache for message-protected tasks
DFXXxx          CICS REQIDS (where xx is a hexadecimal value)